# Choosing a video file format when rendering doesn't work

Tags: rendering, video, file-format

When I want to render my scene as an animation video, I choose mp4, ogg....etc but the resulted file always is .dvd, why is that happening? I'm using version 2.72

Comment: Did you check the output directory, because you check the wrong one, where it contains the old files. Else if you rename '.dvd' to 'mp4' it will play as well

Answer (score 2):

My other [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47323/2843) explains how to render a video (with Sound) in general. You need to make sure in your case that in your *Properties Editor* > *Render tab* in the *Output* Panel your filename is set properly. Most likely it is set to something like `file.dvd` right now which results in your described behaviour. Change it to `//file.mp4` (to get it rendered out next to your blend-file) for example:

[image: File Name]

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the audio codec, not the container format or the video codec.

I would suggest upgrading to 2.79, where the encoding panel has been improved & simplified.