# How to edit video with a third audio channel

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've just started using blender to edit videos (a site recommended it out of a list of free video editors), and for the recordings, I've been using a third audio channel to help separate my speech from the rest of the audio. However I'm not sure how to edit it in blender and i haven't found any tutorials on how to do this. Is there a way in blender or would I have to use another program to edit the audio?

EDIT: to clarify, when recording, my voice is recorded into a third audio channel along with the usual left and right channels in the video file. this was so I could edit out background noises (or me coughing in some cases) without having to mute all sound.
For now i'm using a "push to talk" button to reduce background noise

Comment: Welcome to the Blender.SE! Could you clarify what you means by "editing"? The software has tools for slicing, muting, moving the audio strips and other simple features... (https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/strips/types/audio.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I incorporate audio into my output avi render?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47269/can-i-incorporate-audio-into-my-output-avi-render)

Comment: @Carlo, by editing i just mean muting background noises or me coughing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added information to your original question. It's not so important how many audio channels the video has in your scenario, you want to drop the volume of one of the audio tracks for a cough/sneeze/burp you can keyframe the volume of a track.

[image]

- view the audio track as an audio waveform
- set keyframes at the appropriate places. A sane volume range is between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You just use the VSE to import Sound Strips. They can be either Stereo or Mono files. However, you can place as many as you want to in different channels above each other. In the end, they will be mixed down together into a video when you [use an audio codec](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47323/2843) as well or you can mix it down into a new audio file only (video and image strips etc will be ignored then).

However, you cannot do/use many audio operations other than do panning (left right in stereo), changing volume or pitch, thus changing speed and doing fades. If you need more advanced audio processing like normalization or compressors/equalizers, you'd need a specific audio tool like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) and import that edited Audio Strip into Blender afterwards to include in a movie.