# Split Screen Video- My videos combined won't render with sound?

Tags: video, audio

I looked all over stack exchange, and I couldn't find an answer. So I'm making a video where there is two of me in the same video, by taking two separate videos and combining them. My video with sound renders individually correctly. When I combine it with the other video, combined they don't render with sound. I also did everything I could: turned on "AV-sync", turned on the audio codec, etc... and everything. [image: shows properties with all of the above turned on]

Now, I am just confused.These are the properties of the combined videos I am trying to render into one video. What am I doing wrong? Yes, the audio is turned up as well... thank you. Here is both of the videos in the VSE:

[image]

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the video sequence editor? With the strips? Or however you combine the two cloips. Audio and Video are treated as separate strips in the VSE.

Comment: Yes, there they are. I know you can merge the strips. But, when I do that for some reason the audio unsyncs. @Leander

Answer (score 1):

Your Audio strip is muted (your green "roasting_me.005" strip is very transparent). Just select it and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide it. Or unhide it via the Strip menu. Then it should be rendered in your Video as your encoding settings seem to be [correct](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47323/2843).